# Rails postgreSQL duplicate key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails app that uses postgreSQL.

I recently did a backup of production and restored it to development.

When I try to add a Payment record in development, I get:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "payments_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Yet, there is only one record in the table with id=1 and the payments_id_seq has Current value = 1.

So, whey isn't Rails trying to add id=2 ??

Thanks for the help!

PS - is there a script or command in pgadmin to force the id_seq to be correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably whatever method you used to copy your database didn't update your sequences along the way, a standard dump/restore should have take care of that but if you copied things row-by-row by hand then you'll have to fix things using [`setval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html).

If you only need to fix the sequence for a table `T`, then you could do this from the console:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(%q{
    select setval('T_id_seq', m)
    from (
        select max(id) from T
    ) as dt(m)
})
```

or you could feed that SQL to pgadmin. You'd repeat that for each table `T`.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  But, why is my app trying to save a new record with id=2 when the payments_id_seq has Current value = 1. Shouldn't it be trying to save id=2 ??

Comment: The `id` is assigned by the database and the database gets the next `id` from the sequence. The sequences and the tables disagree about what `id` is next because whatever you used to copy the database didn't reset the sequences along the way.

Answer (score 7):

If you receive a PostgreSQL unique key violation error message ("duplicate key value violates unique constraint..."), probably your primary key index is out of sync, e.g. after populating the database.

Use

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('[table_name]')
```

to fix the sequence for the users table.